# Use current class method inside add_submenu_page()

Tags: plugins, sub-menu

I have a class like below.

```
namespace Inc\Admin;

class Admin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'admin_menu']);
    }

    public function admin_menu()
    {
       add_submenu_page('sports_info', 'Sports Information', 'Sports Information', 'manage_options', [$this,'sports_info_page'], [$this, 'html_page']);
    }

    public function html_page() {
       //some code
    }

    public function sports_info_page() {
      //some code
    }

}
```

I am getting below errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class Inc\Admin\Admin could not be converted to string
```

Error comes from `[$this,'sports_info_page']` of `add_submenu_page()`.

Comment: I don't see how/where/when the parent menu (`sports_info`?) is added, but make sure that you used the correct parent slug. Or did you mean to add a top-level menu instead, e.g. using [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the 5th parameter for [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) should be a string which is the menu slug and yet you supplied a callback (`[$this,'sports_info_page']`). So be sure to use a valid slug like so and the error will be gone:

```php
add_submenu_page(
    'sports_info',             // parent slug
    'Sports Information',      // page title
    'Sports Information',      // menu title
    'manage_options',          // capability
    'your-menu-slug',          // menu slug
    [$this,'sports_info_page'] // callback
);
```